# Группировка по полям с учетом времени?

Tags: postgresql

Есть таблица:
id 
user
operation
timestamp

Каждая операция пользователя записывается и имеет свой код.
Нужно группировать по пользователю и операциям за последние 2 часа. 
То есть вывести список пользователей и их операций если они совершались за последние 2 часа.

Comment: причем тут группировка ? если надо все операции выводить ... По тому что вы написали вам нужен обычный `where timestamp > current_timestamp - interval '2 hour'`

Comment: хотя если могут быть несколько одинаковых operation с разными timestamp то конечно group by стоит добавить.